# How to make formule bigger in org-mode of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I found Org-mode + LaTeX to be a very wonderful tool.  How can I alter the scale of formula?  Currently it is too small for me.  I know how to scale the Emacs font (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>), but this does not work for LaTeX formulas.

How can make the LaTeX formulae bigger in Org-mode?

I have tired to change some parameters, but the problem still remains.

Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the
[documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html#Previewing-LaTeX-fragments)

or `(info "(org) Previewing LaTeX fragments")`

```
You can customize the variable `org-format-latex-options' to
influence some aspects of the preview. In particular, the `:scale'
(and for HTML export, `:html-scale') property can be used to
adjust the size of the preview images.
```

A quick
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`org-format-latex-options`<kbd>RET</kbd>
gives us:

```
org-format-latex-options is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is (:foreground default :background default :scale 1.0 :html-foreground "Black" :html-background "Transparent" :html-scale 1.0 :matchers
             ("begin" "$1" "$" "$$" "\\(" "\\["))


Documentation:
Options for creating images from LaTeX fragments.
[snip]
:scale       a scaling factor for the size of the images, to get more pixels
[snip]
```

For example, to set the scale to `2.0`:

```
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 2.0))
```

Comment: Do not forget to `(require 'org)` in advance.

Comment: But this affects inline and display equations. Is there a way to set separate settings for inline and display equations?

Comment: What if I want to change the scale per file or only the scale of a snippet?